# LXC container fail to load big iptables rules

Tags: iptables, lxc

I'm facing a strange problem when I try to load a big iptables set of rules on a LXC container (it's working fine on a virtual machine).

The container is running Linux Debian 12 bookworm.

I'm able to configure the rules and save them with:

```
 /usr/sbin/netfilter-persistent save
```

However, if I try to load them, I get this error message ( the file is 694 chars length)

```
$ sudo  iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4
sendmsg() failed: Message too long
iptables-restore: line 692 failed: Message too long.
```

What's weird is that if I add the verbose mode it is working fine

```
$ sudo  iptables-restore -v < /etc/iptables/rules.v4 && echo ok
(...)
# Completed on Fri Sep 15 08:57:48 2023
ok
```

However, if I try to load a big file (33750 lines), I'm always getting the "Message too long" error, in verbose mode or not.

All the loading tests are working fine on a virtual machine (same os).

So I'm wondering if there is a line limit or memory limit somewhere in LXC ? I have tried to play with `limits.conf` but it didn't change anything yet.

Any idea ?

**EDIT** Here are more information to reproduce this behavior:

Kernel version:

```
Linux xxxxxx 6.2.16-10-pve #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC PMX 6.2.16-10 (2023-08-18T11:42Z) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Some packages version (guest container):

```
ii  iptables                            1.8.9-2                                 amd64        administration tools for packet filtering and NAT
ii  iptables-persistent                 1.0.20                                  all          boot-time loader for netfilter rules, iptables plugin
ii  libip4tc2:amd64                     1.8.9-2                                 amd64        netfilter libip4tc library
ii  libip6tc2:amd64                     1.8.9-2                                 amd64        netfilter libip6tc library
ii  libnetfilter-conntrack3:amd64       1.0.9-3                                 amd64        Netfilter netlink-conntrack library
ii  libxtables12:amd64                  1.8.9-2                                 amd64        netfilter xtables library
ii  netfilter-persistent                1.0.20                                  all          boot-time loader for netfilter configuration
```

host packages:

```
ii  lxc-pve                              5.0.2-4                             amd64        Linux containers userspace tools
ii  lxcfs                                5.0.3-pve3                          amd64        LXC userspace filesystem
ii  pve-lxc-syscalld                     1.3.0                               amd64        PVE LXC syscall daemon
```

The little ruleset is :

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.9 (nf_tables) on Fri Sep 15 08:57:48 2023
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:block_spam2 - [0:0]
:block_spam1 - [0:0]
:block_spam3 - [0:0]
:incoming_net - [0:0]
:sensitive_daemons - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j block_spam1
-A INPUT -j block_spam2
-A INPUT -j block_spam3
-A INPUT -j sensitive_daemons
-A INPUT -j incoming_net
-A INPUT -j sensitive_daemons
-A block_spam2 -s 1.0.1.0/24 -j DROP
-A block_spam2 -s 84.22.192.0/19 -j DROP
-A block_spam1 -s 103.39.156.0/22 -j DROP
-A block_spam1 -s 5.255.220.0/22 -j DROP
-A block_spam3 -s 87.245.234.136/32 -j DROP
-A block_spam3 -s 217.199.224.0/19 -j DROP
[...] 675 lines here : block_spam[1-3] with a uniq ip address [...]
-A incoming_net -d 192.168.1.248/29 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A incoming_net -d 192.168.1.248/29 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A incoming_net -d 192.168.1.248/29 -p tcp -j DROP
-A sensitive_daemons -s 192.168.1.248/29 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
-A sensitive_daemons -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.24/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A sensitive_daemons -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Sep 15 08:57:48 2023
```

Comment: This could be a bug (to be fixed upstream) or related to limits within the container, but without a ruleset to reproduce this bug, not much to be done about it. Can depend on kernel version, iptables version, iptables-legacy versus iptables-nft, container settings, etc. and of course the unavailable ruleset

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've posted more details

Comment: You should consider using `ipset` to keep host/network addresses for `block_spam*` rules (and likely merge them into just one set), this would be faster. Or just move to nftables and use built in sets.

Comment: Managed to reproduce it. Apparently this requires to be unprivileged (so all attempts with real root didn't fail). This could be related to this change: https://git.netfilter.org/iptables/commit/?id=a3e81c62e8c5abb4158f1f66df6bbcffd1b33240 . I'd advise you to try iptables 1.8.7 (before this change)

Comment: And of course any answer telling you to not use all these entries the way they are used is a correct answer: you should separate data from code.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. `ipset` is perfect (I didn't know this tool). Great ! . However, even if I misused iptables, I beleive that this issue may be a bug in some situations.

Comment: Go and accept the answer then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using ipset to keep host/network addresses for block_spam* rules (and likely merge them into just one set), this would be faster. Or just move to nftables and use built in sets.

Comment: This is the correct way to achieve what I wanted to do and I hope this will help other sysadmins. However, this issue may occur in different situations where `ipset` won't be the solution. In that case, according to @A.B , you should consider downgrading iptables to release 1.8.7.

Answer (score 0):

If you look up the sendmsg() man page you'll see that it does not actually have a response indicating that a message was too large. It does however return ENOBUFS if there is not enough space in the message buffer - similar, but not the same thing. I suspect that is what is happenning here. And is caused when nothing is emptying the message buffer - socket communications have failed in some way. Why is iptables-restore writing to a socket? Most likly its trying to write log entries (or one large one) but that's mostly guesswork. On most modern Linux 'iptables-restore' is a symlink pointing to one of several implementions of packet filtering tools.

If `iptables-restore -v` works, then you have a workaround, however the most LIKELY reason for having lots of firewall rules is because you are adding rules about individual client addresses directly. This is fine for small numbers of addresses but DOES NOT SCALE. As @Tomek says, using `ipset` is a much better solution (this does scale).

Comment: There are two possibilities why it is writing to a socket: 1) DNS resolution (if hostnames are used) 2) It may be using netlink to program rules to the kernel. I suspect that `-v` may be programming every rule separately (to provide feedback) while normally it tries to pack everything in single message and fails due to a size.